Expected value - game involving $8$-sided die
You have been chosen to play a game involving a $8$-sided die. You get to roll the die once, see the result, and then may choose to either stop or roll again. Your payoff is the sum of your rolls, unless this sum is greater than $8$, in which case you "bust" and get nothing. How much would you pay to play this game?
I figured out that we would choose to roll again if  $N \leq 4$, where $N$ is the number we get when we toss the die for the first time and stop if $N = 5, 6, 7$ or $8$. But I am stuck. How should I calculate properly the expected value? Thanks for help!

What does the starting cost have to do with the strategy? Is there some specific goal of a given strategy that you are trying to optimize? Obviously any player would choose to pay zero dollars for this game if given the choice

If you roll a $2$ then roll a $1$, are you allowed to roll a third time?

How did you figure out "we would choose to roll again if $N \le 4$"?

Usually the optimal strategy is determined by selecting the cut off that maximizes expected value. How did you do it?

If I roll a $4$, then by continuing I will either lose $4$ if I bust (with probability $1/2$), or gain an average of $5/2$ (also with $p=1/2$).  So I’d expect to lose $3/4$… and so I wouldn’t roll again in that case.

@whpowell96 it should be more like "what is the maximum amount of money you're willing to pay to play this game"

I guess the question still feels ill-posed to me. You can't compute the expected value without specifying some sort of decision making strategy. Is the question actually "1. What strategy is optimal in [insert sense here]? 2. What are the expected winnings of said strategy?" The maximum one is willing to pay depends on one's measure of optimality. If your goal is to maximize the worst case winnings, then the answer is still zero, for example. Maximizing expected winning is another example, but it isn't stated

I assume here we can keep rolling indefinitely until we choose to stop or we go bust. I also assume that decisions depend only on expected values.
If at the first roll we roll one of $\{4,5,6,7,8\}$, we stop playing. Indeed:
If we roll $8$, we stop playing.
If we roll $7$, we stop playing because playing another round would yield an expected value of the sum of $8\cdot\frac{1}{8}<7$.
If we roll $6$, we stop playing because playing another round would yield an expected value of the sum of $7\cdot\frac{1}{8}+8\cdot\frac{1}{8}<6$.
If we roll $5$, we stop playing because playing another round would yield an expected value of the sum of $6\cdot\frac{1}{8}+7\cdot\frac{1}{8}+8\cdot\frac{1}{8}<5$.
If we roll $4$, we stop playing because playing another round would yield an expected value of the sum of $5\cdot\frac{1}{8}+6\cdot\frac{1}{8}+7\cdot\frac{1}{8}+8\cdot\frac{1}{8}<4$.
If at the first roll we roll one of $\{1,2,3\}$, we keep playing. Indeed:
If we roll $3$, we keep playing because playing another round would yield an expected value of the sum of $4\cdot\frac{1}{8}+5\cdot\frac{1}{8}+6\cdot\frac{1}{8}+7\cdot\frac{1}{8}+8\cdot\frac{1}{8}=\frac{30}{8}>3$. So we roll again, yielding an expected value of the game equal to $\frac{30}{8}$. We stop rolling after the second roll regardless of the value obtained, due to the above.
If we roll $2$, we keep playing because playing another round would yield an expected value of the sum of $3\cdot\frac{1}{8}+4\cdot\frac{1}{8}+5\cdot\frac{1}{8}+6\cdot\frac{1}{8}+7\cdot\frac{1}{8}+8\cdot\frac{1}{8}=\frac{33}{8}>2$. So we roll again, yielding an expected value of the game equal to $\frac{30}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{8}+4\cdot\frac{1}{8}+5\cdot\frac{1}{8}+6\cdot\frac{1}{8}+7\cdot\frac{1}{8}+8\cdot\frac{1}{8}=\frac{30}{8}\cdot \frac{9}{8}$.
If we roll $1$, we keep playing because playing another round would yield an expected value of the sum of $2\cdot\frac{1}{8}+3\cdot\frac{1}{8}+4\cdot\frac{1}{8}+5\cdot\frac{1}{8}+6\cdot\frac{1}{8}+7\cdot\frac{1}{8}+8\cdot\frac{1}{8}=\frac{35}{8}>1$. So we roll again, yielding an expected value of the game equal to $\frac{30}{8}\cdot\frac{9}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{8}+\frac{30}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{8}+\frac{30}{8}=\frac{30}{8}\cdot (\frac{9}{8^2}+\frac{9}{8})$.
So, since all the above rolls have equal probability $1/8$, the expected value of the game is:
$$\frac{30}{8}\bigg(\bigg(\frac{9}{8^2}+\frac{9}{8}\bigg)\cdot \frac{1}{8}+\frac{9}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+1\bigg)\approx 5.3394$$
One would pay less than or equal this expected value to play the game.

To optimize long term winnings, the player needs to have a stopping strategy that optimizes the expected payoff at each step, given the previous rolls. Suppose the k-th dice roll is a random variable represented by $X_k$, player has had $m$ rolls so far and the outcomes are $X_k=x_k,~ k=1...m$, and the total sum of the dice rolls is currently less than $8$. Then for the $(m+1)$-th roll, the expected payoff conditional on the previous rolls is given by
$$\mathbb{E}(\text{payoff}_{m+1}|X_m=x_m,...,X_1=x_1)=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{j=x_1+...+x_m+1}^8j=\frac{9}{2}-\frac{(\sum_i{x_i}+1)\sum_i{x_i}}{16}$$
The expected payoff decreases as the current payoff increases, so there must be a certain payoff beyond which it is not favorable to roll again in the long term. We denote the current payoff $s_k=\sum_{i=1}^k x_i$. We then formulate the stopping condition such that $$\mathbb{E}(\text{payoff}_{k+1})=\frac{9}{2}-\frac{s_k(s_k+1)}{16}<s_k$$
A quick analysis shows that the player needs to stop rolling when $s_k\geq 4$, since at that point the expected payoff is less than the current roll.
With this strategy in hand we can enumerate all possible game paths and hence compute the expected payoff for the game. The easiest way to do this is to write out the expected payoff at each possible number of rolls $k$, using the stop condition to describe the outcomes that lead to each stopping time. It is obvious that the player should never roll more than 4 times, since $s_k\geq k$, and hence $s_4$ always satisfies the stopping condition. We can now write down the expected payoff, this reads:
$$\mathbb{E}(\text{payoff})=\frac{1}{8}\sum_{8\geq s_1\geq 4} s_1+\frac{1}{8^2}\sum_{\substack{s_1\leq 3\\ 8\geq s_2\geq 4}} s_2+\frac{1}{8^3}\sum_{\substack{s_2\leq 3\\8\geq s_3\geq 4}}s_3+\frac{1}{8^4}\sum_{\substack{s_3\leq 3\\8\geq s_4\geq 4}}s_4=\\=\sum_{k=1}^48^{-k}{3\choose k-1}\left[{9\choose 2}-{4\choose 2}\right]=\frac{1}{8}\left(1+\frac{1}{8}\right)^3\frac{9\cdot 8-4\cdot 3}{2}\approx5.3394
$$
